# NGRX nesting multiple feature modules inside each other?

Tags: angular7, ngrx, ngrx-store, ngrx-effects

currently the store Im using is a flat stracture of feature modules, i.e:

```
{
    feature_A: {
       A:'A',
       B:'B'
    },
    feature_B:{
        C:'C',
        D:'D'
    }
}
```

But what I want to do is:

```
{
    feature_A: {
       A:'A',
       B:'B',
       feature_B:{
        C:'C',
        D:'D'
      }
    }
}
```

Maybe something like:
    App.Module

```
StoreModule.forFeature('feature_A', fromFeature_A.feature_A_Reducers)
StoreModule.forFeature('feature_A.feature_B', fromFeature_B.feature_B_Reducers)
```

Was searching for an answer for this on the net didn't really find a real anser other than that its recomended to keep a flat structure of the feature modules.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Feature modules in `ngrx` are just the immediate state off of the root of the object, so there isn't really an idea of a nested feature module.

Instead, you can accomplish similar behavior by still keeping feature B's state abstracted out into different files (reducers, actions, effects...), but treating it as a sub-state of feature A.

You could then create a selector to access specifically feature B's state:

```
const selectFeatureA = createFeatureSelector('feature_A');
const selectFeatureB = createSelector(selectFeatureA, (state) => state.feature_B);
```

Comment: your right... if there's a way that's the way... but we decided to go with the flat store structure without nested objects.